# NP-hard - Definition

Tags: np

The definition of NP-hard problem in Wikipedia is :
NP-hardness (non-deterministic polynomial-time hard), in computational complexity theory, is a class of problems that are, informally, "at least as hard as the hardest problems in NP".

There are NP-hard problems not in NP class. My question (more curiosity) concerns the **NP** in the definition. Since a NP-hard maybe is not in NP class, why we call it **NP**-hard?

When we say we have a NP-complete problem, then this problem is indeed in NP class.

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857244/what-are-the-differences-between-np-np-complete-and-np-hard

Comment: It's just terminology. Maybe it's not optimal, but it's become customary. A problem is NP-hard if it's at least as hard as any problem in NP.

Comment: Yes. I thought also that. There is not any *deeper* explanation.

Comment: Maybe because it could be in NP?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a definition which describes the relationship between hard and complete:

> Given a set `C` of problems and a reduction `R`, it is natural to ask if there are problems `Π ∈ C` such that any problem `Π′∈C`,  `R`-reduces to `Π`. Such “maximal”
>   problems are called in complexity theory complete problems. Let `C` be a class of
>   problems and `R` be a reduction. A problem `Π ∈ C` is said to be `C`-complete (under `R`-reduction) if for any `Π ∈′ C`, `Π′ ≤R Π`. A `C`-complete problem (under reduction `R`) is
>   then (in the sens of this reduction) a computationally hardest problem for class `C`. For instance, in the case of `NP`-completeness, `NP`-complete problems (under [Karp-reduction](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fa33/c3a89a423f0eb00134fd291894949bf9d54e.pdf)) are the hardest problems of `NP` since if one could polynomially solve just one of them, then one would be able to solve in polynomial time any other problem in `NP`. Let `C` be a class of problems and `R` a reduction. A problem `Π` is said to be `C`-hard (under `R`-reduction)
>   if for any `Π ∈′ C`, `R Π≤ Π ′`. **In other words, a problem `Π` is `C`-complete if and only if `Π ∈ C` and `Π` is `C`-hard**.

**References**

- [An Overview on Polynomial Approximation of
  NP-Hard Problems](http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/yjor/37/yujorn37p3-40.pdf)
- [Computers and Intractability: A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fa33/c3a89a423f0eb00134fd291894949bf9d54e.pdf)